# PHP 5.3.6 and PHP 5.3.8 source code compatibility

Tags: php, compatibility

I got PHP 5.3.6 Installed in my computer , and I want to begin creating PHP extensions... so I've setup VC++ 2008 (since PHP 5.3.6 is compiled with vc++ 2008).

I need now to download PHP source code, and All I find is PHP 5.3.8 source code from php.net

My question is: is this version of the source code compatible with the version I've installed in my server?

In other words, can I start creating PHP extensions with the help of this source code, for my version of PHP?

Comment: I don't know how PHP internally works but if you implement a interface that it should only not changes in that two different versions.

Comment: FYI, if you really wanted the source to a specific previous version, you could pull it from SVN: http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/tags/php_5_3_6/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PHP developers promise backward-compatibility at least for micro-version updates (The z in x.y.z), thus there should be no problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily find out yourself with the PHP changelog: http://de.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php

From 5.3.6 -> 5.3.7 there were only bugfixes and from 5.3.7 -> 5.3.8 there were only hotfixes for bugs introduced in 5.3.7.